# Django Rest Framework not accepting JWT Authentication Token

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I am using the [Django Restful API Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org) together with [Simple JWT](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and have successfully created a URL for receiving and refreshing a user token.
In order to try out the authentication using the token, I have created a view that simply lists all the posts inside the database. I have then assigned the `IsAuthenticated` class to the view.

As expected, I get an error message saying that the authentication credentials were not provided. I then went ahead and made a simple `GET` request using Postman, with the authentication token provided in the "Authorization" tab. The type was set to "Bear Token". Unfortunately, I still get the message "Authentication credentials were not provided." with a 403 Forbidden code.

I have also tried to provide the token in the Headers, as well as make CURL requests, everything to no avail.

My view looks like this:

```
class PostListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Post.objects.filter()
```

This is the serializer:

```
class PostListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('__all__')
```

The settings.py of the Django project:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ['django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend'],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ['rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny'],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES:': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',)
}
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True  # For testing purposes
```

I have followed several different tutorials online, read through numerous posts as well as followed the official documentation of Simple JWT.

Answer (score 0):

Well what you are doing is trying to filter the data while your basic purpose is to just list your model. For filtering make sure your go through the documentation [DRF Filtering](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/).

Try these changes in your code. I hope it will work for you.

Settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ],
}
```

Views.py

```
class UserList(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostListSerializer
```

After this try to hit your API with access token. To learn more about generic views you can go through this link [Generic Views in DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/).

Comment: I have the filter enabled because I need it somewhere else. But from what I understand, it shouldn't have anything to do with my problem. Nevertheless, I tried your suggestion and removed those lines. Unfortunately without any results, the problem still persists.

Comment: Are you running django on Apache?

Comment: I am currently trying to get this working locally, using the Django development server.